# What are some good results to know for an interview?

Tags: sequences-and-series, ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform

For an undergraduate interview for university in maths & theoretical physics, what are some good results to have on hand and (where relevant) know the derivation of? e.g.:
$$\frac{d}{dx}[x^x]=x^x(ln(x)+1)$$
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n^2}=\frac{\pi^2}{6}$$
$${1+\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{\ddots}}}=\phi$$
$$\frac{d^2x(t)}{dt^2}+\omega^2x(t)=0\Rightarrow x(t)=x_0cos(\omega t)+\frac{v_0}{\omega}sin(\omega t)$$
Additionally, are there any techniques that might be helpful to know, to answer questions with more sophistication than required for high-school exams? e.g.: the Laplace transform to answer questions on SHM.

Comment: The most important technique in all of calculus is expanding in power series.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the system in England. What is the purpose of this interview for your university? Are you being interviewed before being allowed to the university? Also, mathematics is more than just calculus. Being able to prove certain assertions is (in my opinion) much more important. Basic group theory, linear algebra and basic analysis are good starting points for learning proof strategies. Also, Coxeter has some decent books on geometry (about triangles, congruences, Ceva's theorem,...) that will teach you how to prove things (without heavy mathematical machinery).

Comment: $$e^{ix}=\cos x+i \sin x$$ in case you know how to add and multiply complex numbers, is an extremely useful identity to have on hand, especially for trigonometric problems

Comment: @Mathematician42, the interview is to ensure competence and interest in the course, and is used for admission selection purposes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are about to be interviewed as part of the application process to be admitted to university, make sure you are competent with differentiation in all its forms especially the Chain Rule, and Integration, especially recognising when to use the Chain Rule in reverse, or substitution, as opposed to Integration by Parts. You should also know all the main trig identities.

However, the most useful skill to acquire is the ability to sketch graphs: interviewers frequently ask candidates to sketch a perhaps unfamiliar graph because it is a good test of mathematical insight and general knowledge and of problem-solving skills.